# ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using `@zeit/next-css` to import css files into my components and pages file but it's throwing me this error

`./styles/navbar.css` importing this css file in my `navbar.js` in components and I'm getting this error

```
ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using
     an options object that does not match the API schema.
- options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals? }
```

my `next.config.js` is placed where `package.json` is

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withCSS();
```

my package json

```
{
  "name": "transfer-to",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "9.0.7",
    "react": "16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "16.10.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't any problem until today, suddenly after yarn dev I faced with this issue

Answer (score 7):

I faced same issue after upading css-loader but I solved it.

If you check css-loader readme, then I noticed that "localIdentName" moved into modules key (it is possible that isn't a recent change, just my artifacts were old).
My current working config is:

```
{
    loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
    options: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        modules: true,
        modules : {
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
        },
    },
},
```

Old wrong config was:

```
{
    loader: "css-loader",
    options: {
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
        sourceMap: isDevelopment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For temporary fix your problem, remove "^" symbol from these packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "1.0.1",
    "next": "9.0.2",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0"
    ...
  }
```

It looks like a buggy updated version for these packages.

Answer (score 0):

In the **webpack.config.js**

```
{
          test: cssRegex,
          exclude: cssModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
            modules: true,
            //localIdentIName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
          }),
          sideEffects: true,
    }
```

I commented on **localIdentName** and it worked.

**//localIdentIName: '[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]'**

It might be wrong to comment on it. But I need to still investigate more about it.

If I add it gives:-

ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using
an options object that does not match the API schema.

- options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:
  object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals? }

Answer (score 0):

**If you are doing the changes in config file for load css. Then your object should be like Below**
*My React version is 6.14.11*

```
       {
          test: cssRegex,
          exclude: cssModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction
              ? shouldUseSourceMap
              : isEnvDevelopment,
            modules : {
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
            },
          }),
```

Answer (score 0):

My web pack config had an issue with spelling

```
module: {
    rules: [
         {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader',
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        modules: true,
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: 'less-loader',
                },
            ],
        },
 .......
```

I used module instead of modules. Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue,
*****'ValidationError**: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.'***
I tried all solutions,but those couldn't work for me
I removed all those two lines:

```
module:true
```

localIdentName: '[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]',

and I created  layout css file with name ,let's say layout.module.css
and in js file, I import it like, and  use like below

```
 import  classes from './Layout.module.css'
<main className={classes.Content}>
    {props.children}
</main>
```

so i think this apporoach is suitable for latest react version

hope this will help to you also